# C# Use checkBox in dataGridView and get sum rows of a column that checked is true

Tags: c#, datagridview

I locate a column checkBox as column0 in datagridview. I want to get sum rows of column1 that column0 checked is true. I used  this code :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
        {
            sum += double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

    textBox1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

but it doesnt work correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work correctly" ? Is it WinForm ?

Comment: Yes. It is WinForm. Value of textBox1 was change for every events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

```
textBox1.Text = (dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
      .Where( r => Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[0].Value).Equals(true))
      .Sum(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Cells[1].Value))).ToString();
```

Comment: this code works after next run. May I use my code in another events of dataGridView?

Comment: Yes just create a Method for it and call the method from all events you want to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

To select all the check boxes in the check box column in C# DataGridView:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = true;
        }
```